# android studio ctrl space replace class names glitch

Tags: android, android-studio, keyboard-shortcuts, autocorrect

I like to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to find suggestions to replace names. I used it in Eclipse. And now I am using it in Android Studio. The Android Studio version is not working as I want it to. Say I have a class called `ILoveCats`. But for whatever reason I have it misspelled as `ILoveHats`. If I place the cursor between  `I` and `L` and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, sure enough it will show the correct `ILoveCats`. But then if I click <kbd>Enter</kbd> it replaces `ILoveHats` with `ILoveCatsLoveHats`. Is there a place where I can set this to behave properly: so it shows `ILoveCats` upon replacement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After you have the suggestions open with `Ctrl + Space` you should be using `Tab` instead of `Enter`. `Tab` inserts and overwrites while `Enter` just inserts.